# How to use help method to verify that the instant field's method got invoked?

Tags: spock

My test class like this:

```
public class HandlerTest extends Specification {
  Handler hander
  EventBus eventBus=Mock()     

  def setup(){
    handler=new Handler(eventBus)
  }

  def "test something"(){
     given:
     ....
     when:
     ....
     then://.....Here,I want to use help method 
      verifyBunchOfThingsHappenedOn()
  }

 def  verifyBunchOfThingsHappenedOn(){
    assert 1*eventBus.fireEvent(....)
    ......
 }
}
```

When running this,got:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.test.HandlerTest.verifyBunchOfThingsHappenedOn(HandlerTest.groovy:194)
.......
```

And I thought maybe the instant field caused this problem,so tried to pass local variable to help method,but got the same result:

```
   def "test something"(){
     given:
     ....
     when:
     ....
     then://.....Here,I want to use help method 
      verifyBunchOfThingsHappenedOn(eventBus)
  }

 def  verifyBunchOfThingsHappenedOn(EventBus eventBus){
    assert 1*eventBus.fireEvent(....)
    ......
 }
```

So,question is:

How to use  help method to verify that the instant field's method got invoked?

Comment: It's all explained in the [official documentation](http://docs.spockframework.org).

Answer (score 0):

You can include default interactions directly in the `Mock` as explained [here](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#declaring-interactions-at-mock-creation-time-new-in-0-7).

Here is some fully functional, compileable source code:

**Dummy classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class EventBus {
    public void fireEvent(String event) {
        System.out.println("Firing event: " + event);
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Handler {
    private EventBus eventBus;

    public Handler(EventBus eventBus) {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
    }

    public void handle(String event) {
        eventBus.fireEvent(event);
    }
}
```

**Spock test:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app

import spock.lang.Specification

class HandlerTest extends Specification {
    Handler handler
    EventBus eventBus = Mock() {
        1 * fireEvent(_)
    }

    def setup(){
        handler = new Handler(eventBus)
    }

    def "test something"() {
        expect: handler.handle("My event")
    }

    def "test something else"() {
        expect: handler.handle("Another event")
    }
}
```